# Hide column header in ant design and keep the data

Tags: reactjs, datatable, antd

I have a case where I want to show the data in the table rows but hide the word for that column in the header, here is a screenshot:

[image]

In this case I want to remove the word `id` from the header but keep the data which in my case those arrows, I didn't find a way how to do it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the word from header, you have to remove title which you provide in column

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).